# Translating grid to USGS .dem in C# via GDAL

Tags: raster, c#, gdal, dem

I am attempting to translate ArcInfo binary grids to USGS DEM format (.dem). I have installed the GDAL .NET bindings thru [this build installer](https://web.archive.org/web/20130920025909/http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1500-gdal-1-8-0-mapserver-5-6-6.zip). I can get to GDAL in my C# add-in I am working on. However, it seems that I cannot create a USGS DEM:

```
Gdal.AllRegister();
GDAL.Dataset originalImage = Gdal.Open("C:\\65587895\\hdr.adf", GDAL.Access.GA_ReadOnly);
Driver demDriver = Gdal.GetDriverByName("USGSDEM");

int x = originalImage.RasterXSize;
int y = originalImage.RasterYSize;

Dataset dsDem = demDriver.Create("C:\\Data\\65587895\\foo.dem", x, y, 1, DataType.GDT_Int16, null);
```

Gives the error:

```
System.ApplicationException: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.
```

I thought the USGSDEM format was read/write...am I wrong on that? The [formats list](https://gdal.org/formats_list.html) says that creation of USGSDEM is supported, but a run of `demDriver.GetMetadata(null)` to get the metadata from the USGSDEM driver results in no return of `DCAP_CREATE=YES`, only `DCAP_CREATECOPY=YES`, which makes me cringe, thinking that indeed the `GDALDriver::Create()` method is **not** implemented for the USGSDEM format.

Any thoughts or experience with this? Any other thoughts on translating binary grids to DEMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you use the `CreateCopy` method instead, since the `Create` method is indeed not implemented for the USGSDEM format:

```
OSGeo.GDAL.Dataset dsDem = demDriver.CreateCopy(c.outputFile, originalImage, 0, null, new Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate(ProgressFunc), "Sample Data");
```

I must admit that after not getting many responses here, I asked this question on the gdal-dev osgeo mailing list, which is where this answer came from.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_usgsdem.html) goes into more details, particularly on Creation Issues for USGSDEM formats.

I'm pretty sure you need to pass some creation option in the last parameter of `Create` where you have it set as null. The `gdal_translate` example at the bottom of that page might help you determine what these are, which you can explore at the command prompt.