# Read .DEM (USGS) fIles with C#

Tags: c#, .net, dem, elevation, coordinates

I have a huge number of .DEMs and have been investigating how to process them into something useful.

Does anyone know how, or even if it is possible to read coordinates and elevation data from .DEMs using .NET?  Specifically C#.

Comment: useful for what purpose?

Comment: T'was a while ago now, but it was to do some flood modeling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp). I [needed to go the other way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9609/translating-grid-to-usgs-dem-in-c-via-gdal), from grid to DEM.

Comment: To grids would be fine, im trying to create "calculated" contours from them... tricky stuff without C++ or FME as far as i can tell.